# JBPM 6.0.0 Final meta data information retrieval

Tags: jbpm

In JBPM 6.0.0 Final, in my workflow there are several tasks which are carried one after another. If at any task User is struck, Can JBPM read the meta data information to show where the user is struck at run time.

Answer (score 0):

In jBPM console - > Process instances you can look for instances and information related to the tasks the User has taken.